# « Il y a quelque chose de louche là-dedans / là-dessus / là-dessous » Which to use?

Tags: choix-de-mot

D'habitude, je sais ne pas mélanger ces trois mots. Par exemple, je n'emploie que « là-dessus » dans la phrase :

> On n'a pas le temps de polémiquer **là-dessus**.

Et uniquement « là-dedans » ci-dessous :

> Qu'est-ce que notre passé vient faire **là-dedans** ?

Pour ce qui est de la phrase suivante, en revanche, ces trois mots m'ont l'air tous plus vraisemblables les uns que les autres. Se pourrait-il qu'il existe une nuance là-dedans ?

> Il y a quelque chose de louche **là-dedans**.
>
> Il y a quelque chose de louche **là-dessus**.
>
> Il y a quelque chose de louche **là-dessous**.

Comment: « Qu'est-ce que ça vient faire la-dessous », « là-dessus », « là-haut », « là-bas », etc. est possible suivant le contexte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Il y a quelque chose de louche **là-dessus*** ne se dit - et ne s'écrit - pas. Peut-être qu'un contexte très spécifique pourrait donner du sens à cette phrase, mais aucun exemple ne me vient en tête. Donc, considère ça comme une mauvaise solution

Les deux autres phrases (*là-dessous* et *là-dedans*) me semblent tout à fait correctes mais ont, cependant, une très légère nuance.

---

#### Là-dedans

> *Cette histoire ne me parait pas claire, il y a quelque chose de louche là-dedans.*

L'utilisation de *là-dedans* est logique : **dans** cette histoire, quelque chose est louche.

#### Pourquoi *là-dessous* et pas *là-dessus* ?

*Là-dessous* inclut une notion de dissimulation, de quelque chose qui est caché, masqué. On pourrait aussi utiliser *derrière* qui évoque ces mêmes notions :

> *Il y a quelque chose de louche **derrière cette histoire.***

En utilisant *là-dessous*, donc, on suggère qu'une information importante de l'histoire est dissimulée (que ce soit par un mensonge, un non-dit, une erreur, un oubli). Par exemple :

> Paul prétend qu'il a remboursé Marie, pourtant j'ai vu Marie hier et elle m'a dit qu'elle n'avait pas parlé à Paul depuis la dernière fois. *Il y a quelque chose de louche **là-dessous**.*
>
> *> Je pense que Paul est un menteur, il n'a pas réellement remboursé Marie*

On pourrait ici utiliser également *là-dedans* mais cela serait moins accusateur envers Paul.

> Paul prétend qu'il a remboursé Marie, pourtant j'ai vu Marie hier et elle m'a dit qu'elle n'avait pas parlé à Paul depuis la dernière fois. *Il y a quelque chose de louche **là-dedans**.*
>
> *> Je pense que quelque chose ne va pas dans cette histoire mais ce n'est pas forcément Paul qui ment. Peut-être lui a-t-il envoyé de l'argent qu'elle n'a pas encore reçu, ou peut-être que j'ai mal compris ce que m'a dit Marie.*

---

Bien sûr cette nuance est, comme je le disais, très légère et dans la plupart des cas les deux phrases fonctionneront. De plus, ma réponse ne s'appuie sur aucune convention de la langue française, il s'agit simplement de la façon dont je, en tant que française, le perçois.

Comment: Mention spéciale à *"là-dessous"* pour son interaction avec [cacher la poussière sous le tapis](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cacher_la_poussi%C3%A8re_sous_le_tapis).

Comment: @YohannV. ... Ainsi qu'avec "Il y a anguille sous roche" :)

Answer (score 1):

On polémique *sur* un sujet, mais quelque chose peut venir ou être n'importe où.

« On n'a pas eu le temps de polémiquer là-bas » et autres est cependant possible, dans ce cas, il s'agit de l'endroit où l'on a polémiqué, pas ce sur quoi on l'a fait.